# 90 Day Review will be late

Tags: compensation

I have recently been employed at a company in which I have attended school for and sub-sequentially attained an internship at this company through my school. I was ecstatic, I seemed to have lucked out. I was hired at 10 cents higher than my minimum wage job that I had during school during my internship. That's fine I am an intern. I was then hired at the same company and I received a negligible raise for a starting wage. I was promised a 90 day review in... 90 days. but 2 days before hand I asked if it was happening on the promised day and I was told that it would not happen for awhile. I do not want to work in my field (IT) for the same wage as a worker at walmart (not that there's anything wrong with that but I went to school and do a heck of alot more than IT) Am I being over sensitive? and also what could my plan of action be? (Note this is a small buisness, Post Note: I have not used this stackexchange sub forum before so If I am in error during my posting please inform me and I will change it and reformat) Thanks!!

Comment: Potentially applicable: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid

Comment: This is somewhat applicable, and gives me some insight. but I think this applies more towards larger companies. At my small business that I work at being IT means I am in charge of 90% of things that plug into the wall or run on electricity. This includes upper end IT stuff such as database work and app development.

Comment: Are you still classified as an intern? As an intern you normally get a lower salary, or sometimes no salary in fact. You seem to acknowledge this as you say "That's fine I am intern", but your question seems to be that you feel you are not being paid enough after 90 days of your internship.

Comment: No, I was hired. after 180 hours of being an intern. When I was hired I was given my "Hiring wage" as well as a promise for the 90 day review and a 1 year review.

Comment: Rynoc, I see lots of similarity between the question linked above.  I would lightly push to get the 90 day review at lease scheduled.  At that meeting bring up average salary in the area for the position you do.  If they are still reluctant you can always start looking for a new position.

Comment: @WindRaven has nailed it (make this an answer and I'll upvote it :) ).  If they are pushing the date out, it _cannot_ be open ended and they need to commit to a _new_ date.  Was there anything in your contract (ie, in writing anywhere) about the 90 day pay review?

Comment: No unfortunately there is nothing in writing and I have no contract. I was hired after my internship hours were done. (Which not having a contract is a mistake on my part, I chalked that stuff up to the fact that it is a small family owned business and they wouldnt take advantage of me)

Comment: So you currently have _no_ employment contract whatsoever?  You should _probably_ get that resolved as part of your review....!